# I accidentally deleted a very important zip file through NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

i was working on my NetBeans and i accidentally deleted a zip folder that was on my desktop...a very important all through netbeans on the left side of netbeans you can see all your projects and one of my projects was on the desktop of my mac.
i selected it and then i open the source file selected that zip file and press the delete button on my keyboard it asked me if i wanted to delete i said yes...i though it was going to remove only on the NetBeans table not on all my computer source ... it even didn't went to the trash...i assume if that happen i must have a way to get back that file...like it moved to other fold or something....please you gotta help me

Comment: But seriously, if you haven't been using TimeMachine and don't have access to any HDD recovery tools, you may need to get a pro to look at the drive.

Answer (score 91):

In NetBeans select (highlight) the project that contained the ZIP file.  Under Versioning, select Local History -> Revert Deleted.  See if your ZIP file comes back.  If not, you're probably out of luck.

Version control and backups are your friends.

Comment: Phew. Just switched to from Netbeans to Eclipse and deleted 10 classes by accident... I assumed Ctrl+Z would do it... How wrong I was... Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you have deleted a folder containing files the "Revert deleted" won't work. To work around this, re-create the folder and then try again to "Revert deleted" and the files should show up.

Comment: I deleted files via the terminal and the rm command. This still restored an *almost* complete version. Boom!

Answer (score 40):

Do not panic. Its very easy. Follow the steps:

1. Right click on the folder/directory that the files had been deleted.
2. Choose Local History – Restore Deleted
3. Done

Comment: Disaster averted!!! And by disaster I mean rewriting about 5 minutes of work. Still I'm thrilled, thank you!

Comment: You posted this same answer in a different question. It is not helpful if you have deleted the entire project and all source files.

Answer (score 17):

In Netbeans, there is also the option of History->Revert Deleted.

e.g. right click on the object in the tree owning the object that was deleted, and choose the above menu option.

History retention is set from the Tools->Options menu, under the Miscellaneous tab and the Versioning systems in the left-hand pane.  I think the default retention time is 7 days.

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse and Idea both have a mechanism to restore local history, this includes deleted files. Netbeans [seems to have similar](http://blogs.oracle.com/plamere/entry/saved_by_netbeans_local_history). Hope this helps.

You possibly can recover the deleted file by using the Refactor->Undo[Safely Delete] option.

Answer (score 3):

nope. it wiped it clean. you can install some file recovery software and get it back in no time (just google "file recovery" and you'll get a million tools)

Comment: But in the meantime, it's better not to use at all the computer (don't shut it down, just leave it as it is), to minimize disk writings.