# How to recover deleted folder from Netbeans project?

Tags: netbeans

Accidently deleted the wrong folder from Netbeans! Can it be recovered?

Comment: If you used a source code control system like git or subversion it could.

Comment: Yes it can. See this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900992/retrieve-recover-deleted-netbeans-project

Answer (score -1):

You can Start with this simple tip :

```
1- Right click on the folder/directory that the files had been deleted.
2- Choose Local History – Restore Deleted
3- Done
```

If it doesn't Work you will need to use a recovery software : 
 I highly recommend R-Studio, the demo version might be able to recover your files: [r-studio.com](http://www.r-studio.com/)

Or you can also use [recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva)

Answer (score -1):

If you accidentally delete a folder on Netbean, the way to recover it is as follows. You can't revert deleted folders but you can revert deleted files. Follow these steps.

1. Recreate the folder you deleted in your Netbean project. (You may
   not be able to create the folder within Netbean, in that case you
   can use mkdir command to create the folder )
2. Right click that folder in Netbeans and go to History -> revert
   deleted (you should see a list of deleted files that relate to that
   particular folder.
3. Repeat for each folder and sub-folder

Note: This solution work for both Windows and Linux.

Source : follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19148386/3581386). 

I had the same problem as well and get it solved with the solution of this post.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.