# undelete file from ming

Tags: git, rm

I'm writting a php app on a windows 7 machine and I'm using git command line utility from `mingw32`. The problem is that I just remived a very important file of my project by mistake.

This is the command on which i didn't pay attention and disaster is on my sholders now:
`rm git diff include/class/ReportBuilder.php`

If I do `git status` I see it in:`Changes to be commited` but I can't find it anymore.

Do you have any idea about how can I undelete a file removed with `rm` from mingw32. My file was not in the repository, but I've worked 2 weeks on it :(((

Comment: edited my answer based on the recent post addition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using netbeans and luckly for me, ntbeans has undelete procedure built in. Thank you Netbeans. Thank you stackoverflow for having this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8179717/86112

So, the solutin is:
right click on Project->History->Revert Deleted

Answer (score 2):

If the file was not tracked then this is not related to git. `rm` just deletes the file as usual, so you can rely only on backups.

If the file was added to the index you can try `git checkout include/class/ReportBuilder.php` but this won't get you the latest version, only the version from the latest `git add`.

Comment: ty for your reply. unfortunately I never added that file to the repository :(

Comment: @doledoug then you cannot see it in `git status`. And I didn't mention adding to the repo, only to the index.