# How do i reopen netbeans project after delete?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I delete the project under the Netbeans 8.0.2 now it seems that i can't reopen the project. 
The folder is there but when i try open project the java icon is not shown any more and the nbproject folder is also deleted.

I tried to creating new project and coping the src folder but it show a lot of error ?

[image]

Comment: maybe you can't open it because you deleted it

Comment: it just delete the project from netbeans but all the files and folder are still there , i should have used the close project

Comment: This is a good opportunity to start getting in the habit of saving backups with a version control system (e.g. git): https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html.  But in this case, you can probably import: [File > New Project > Existing Sources](https://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/project-setup.html?print=yes#existing-java-sources)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve/Recover deleted Netbeans project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900992/retrieve-recover-deleted-netbeans-project)

Comment: If you delete the probject from within NetBeans, it will delete source and related directories (`lib`, `nbproject`,`build`,  etc), but will leave any files you might have added (that wasn't under `src`), so basically, no, you can recover from it

Comment: How is this a duplicate question , the other question  is suggesting to use recuva as an answer and i still got the source code under the src im not trying to recover the delete source file but looking for the proper way to reopen it in netbeans again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restore your project with the following steps:

- Delete the `nbproject` folder
- Restart netbeans
- Create a new project from existing sources.

Comment: i got too many unnecessary duplicate packages but does seems to work

Answer (score 2):

The java icon doesn't show because when you delete the Project from Netbeans without deleting the path, some of the files are deleted causing the Project to be recognised as a folder. If you just want to remove some Projects from Project tab in Netbeans, just close them (there is an option if you left click on a Project). By Closing a Project you won't have any problem reopening it.

Comment: Best answer ✓. I think this is a bug. If I delete the project from netbeans, it means just remove project from there. Any way. Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is a solution; it's more of an explanation. How can one resolve this issue since he didn't use the close option?